# How could I optimize/index this query better?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have the following query in a Postgres database...

```
SELECT 
   SUM("balance_transactions"."fee") AS sum_id 
   FROM "balance_transactions" 
   JOIN charges ON balance_transactions.source = charges.balance_id 
   WHERE "balance_transactions"."account_id" = 6 
      AND (balance_transactions.type = 'charge' 
      AND charges.refunded = false 
      AND charges.invoice IS NOT NULL) 
      AND ("balance_transactions"."created" BETWEEN '2013-12-20' AND '2014-01-19');
```

It tends to take a little while to run and here's the output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
 Aggregate  (cost=7263.70..7263.71 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=23.367..23.367 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=28.04..7262.31 rows=556 width=4) (actual time=0.403..23.247 rows=938 loops=1)
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on balance_transactions  (cost=28.04..1798.91 rows=754 width=22) (actual time=0.349..0.834 rows=943 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((account_id = 6) AND ((type)::text = 'charge'::text) AND (created >= '2013-12-20 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created <= '2014-01-19 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_balance_transactions_account_type_created  (cost=0.00..27.85 rows=754 width=0) (actual time=0.327..0.327 rows=943 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((account_id = 6) AND ((type)::text = 'charge'::text) AND (created >= '2013-12-20 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created <= '2014-01-19 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
         ->  Index Scan using index_charges_on_balance_id on charges  (cost=0.00..7.24 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.023..0.023 rows=1 loops=943)
               Index Cond: ((balance_id)::text = (balance_transactions.source)::text)
               Filter: ((NOT refunded) AND (invoice IS NOT NULL))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 0
 Total runtime: 23.788 ms
(11 rows)
```

So, what are some things I could do to speed that query up?

EDIT: Here are the current indexes on those tables...

```
-- BALANCE TRANSACTIONS INDEXES --
"balance_transactions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"index_balance_transactions_account_type_created" btree (account_id, type, created)
"index_balance_transactions_on_account_id" btree (account_id)
"index_balance_transactions_on_account_id_and_item_id" btree (account_id, item_id)
"index_balance_transactions_on_plan" btree (plan)
"index_balance_transactions_on_source" btree (source)
"index_balance_transactions_on_item_id" btree (item_id)
"index_balance_transactions_on_type" btree (type)

-- CHARGES INDEXES --
"charges_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"index_account_ref_created_plan" btree (account_id, refunded, created, plan)
"index_charges_on_account_id" btree (account_id)
"index_charges_on_account_id_and_amount" btree (account_id, amount)
"index_charges_on_account_id_and_amount_and_created" btree (account_id, amount, created)
"index_charges_on_account_id_and_paid_and_created" btree (account_id, paid, created)
"index_charges_on_account_id_and_balance_id" btree (account_id, balance_id)
"index_charges_on_customer" btree (customer)
"index_charges_on_invoice" btree (invoice)
"index_charges_on_is_projected" btree (is_projected)
"index_charges_on_is_projected_and_projected" btree (is_projected, projected)
"index_charges_on_parent_charge" btree (parent_charge)
"index_charges_on_plan" btree (plan)
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide the indexes (and their specifics) that are currently on `balance_transactions` and `charges`?

Comment: The plan seems mostly sane, apart from text conversions that you might want to look into, and a filter operator (but you've plenty of indexes already). It runs in 23ms; what's wrong with that?

Comment: @Denis Well, it gets run a LOT. A single web request may call that query (with only the date range changed) thousands of times. So, it adds up.

Comment: @Shpigford - when you need a maximum speed, then using text field in JOIN is not good "ON balance_transactions.source = charges.balance_id". Second - thousands queries in one call is second bad design - you can try to use a stored procedure as minimum.

Comment: @Shpigford - Why can't you create one query that encapsulates the thousand requests?

Comment: @jjanes Totally agree, this is solving the wrong problem. Use one set operation that returns the result of the thousand requests.